# How to determine a file path in Maven project?

Tags: java, maven

I am using Maven for a project. In one of my java class, I need to grab a property file. I cannot use absolute file location but relative path. I tried several ways but no luck.

The java is in

```
myProject/src/main/java/com/some/myConfiguration.java
```

The property file is in

```
myProject/src/main/com/some/resources/myProperties/myFeatures.properties
```

And in my java, I have some code like this

```
String filePath = "correct/path/to/myFeatures.properties";
File repositoryFile = new File(filePath);
```

So my problem is what I should give to `filePath`

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- put your `myFeatures.properties` property file inside `src/main/resources` as suggested by [Maven's Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)
- access it in your Java code using:

  `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myFeatures.properties")`;

Comment: This method returns a java.io.InputStream object. In my case, I need to create a temp file so it is the better way to do it. And yes, I am following the Maven standard layout now.

Comment: if any one have idea  that how can we make a java.io.File object after getting java.io.InputStream please share with me

Answer (score 0):

You can try `this.getClass.getResource("/myProperties/myFeatures.properties")` because the compiled path of `resources` is under the `class` path.

Comment: The OP's `/myProperties/myFeatures.properties` doesn't reside in `src/main/resources`. So, this isn't going to work without the first step given in Adam Siemion's answer.

Comment: The method returns a URL object. And a small typo, it needs to be this.getClass().getResource()